# Django registration, first and last names, no username

Tags: django, facebook, registration

I am using the django-registration package. I do not want people to have a username but to enter instead their first and last names. Like on Facebook. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django auth (and by extension admin) requires a username - full  stop.  So you'll have to go to some effort to work around that.

You have a few issues to consider: 
1) Firstname Lastname will rapidly lead to collisions.  What does your service do when the second "John Smith" wants to sign up?

2) You have to create a username, so you'll likely use a hash of firstname_lastname.  Again, what do you do when you get a second exact match?

3) You'll have to write a custom auth backend to take care of the login, this isn't actually that hard.

A prototype of the solution to #2 can be found [here](https://github.com/tedtieken/django-simple-registration/blob/master/forms.py) - basically in the form processing, generate a random unique hash.

```
while True:
    self.cleaned_data['username'] = str(md5(str(self.data['email']) + str(random.random())).hexdigest())[0:30]
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        break
```

Comment: Couldn't I just use the e-mail address as the username ?

Comment: @jim you can't use email because the field is too small (30 chars) and the field validation doesn't accept @. But you can replace the @ with _ or something, and special case handle the collisions if the address is too long. You still need a custom auth.

Comment: Thank you David. Has anybody done that before ? Where can I find some example code ?

Comment: email is 75 characters max, username is 30 characters max.  I added that to a different answer, but that answer is not here any longer.  Part of the code at the link i gave in the answer implements email as username.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND and declare it in settings.py : 
ie :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'yourapp.backends.NoUsernameModelBackend',
)
```

The code should look like this :

```
class NoUsernameModelBackend
    def authenticate(self, first_name=None,last_name, password=None):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name)
            if user.check_password(password):
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:        
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then you need to define your own AuthenticationForm to take a first_name and a last_name instead of a username and define the url pattern accordingly.

in urls :

```
(r'^login/?$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'authentication_form':'FullNameAuthenticationForm'}, 'login'),
```

Comment: This code is partway there, but unless you guarantee that (firstname, lastname) are unique somehow User.objects.get(...) will fail if you have two john smith's.

Comment: @Ted of course this is a weird requirement to avoid username and requiring a login solely based on first and last name but that's he asked. And this is one way to do it. Actually you can re-use some of that code to allow people to login with there email (this is a more probable use case)

Comment: Oh, I followed, I was just pointing out that if your solution is used you would also have to ensure programatically that there is one and only one person with each First-Last combination.